# FancyBox 3 image size on mobiles in landscape

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-3

I'm using FancyBox 3 to display a gallery of images.
It works great except for the mobiles in landscape orientation, where the image is not taking all the available space.
Like here: http://prntscr.com/j7d6xk

I can't get it to use 100% of the available height.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove top/bottom spacing using CSS:

```
.fancybox-slide--image {
    padding: 0;
}
```